# Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, linear-groups

Let $\mathbb M(n;\mathbb R)$ denote the set of all real matrices (identified with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ and endowed with its usual topology) and $GL(n;\mathbb R)$ denote the group of all invertible matrices. Let $G$ be a subgroup of $GL(n;\mathbb R)$. Define
$$H = \{ A \in G \mid \text{there exists } \phi : [0, 1] \rightarrow G \text{ continuous, such that } \phi (0)=A,\phi(1)=I\}.$$
Then is $H$ a normal subgroup?

Comment: Have you checked if this $H$ is a subgroup at least

Comment: if A,B in H, ten there exist continous function g and h such that g(0)= A, g(1)=I, h(0)=B,h(1)=I. Let f=gh pointwise multiplied, but here is some problem